# Port Upgrade Outdated fails with "Failed to patch py26-numpy"

Tags: python, numpy, macports

Xcode: Version 9.2 (9C40b)
OSX: 10.13.3

I ran port self update first and then port upgrade outdated:

```
MrMuscle:Desktop mnewman$ port version
Version: 2.4.2
MrMuscle:Desktop mnewman$   sudo port -v upgrade outdated
--->  Computing dependencies for py26-numpy.
--->  Applying patches to py26-numpy
--->  Applying patch-numpy_core_setup.py.26.diff
Executing:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_python_py-numpy/py26-numpy/work/numpy-1.11.3" && /usr/bin/patch -p0 < '/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py-numpy/files/patch-numpy_core_setup.py.26.diff'
patching file numpy/core/setup.py
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file numpy/core/setup.py.rej
Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_python_py-numpy/py26-numpy/work/numpy-1.11.3" && /usr/bin/patch -p0 < '/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py-numpy/files/patch-numpy_core_setup.py.26.diff'
Exit code: 1
Error: Failed to patch py26-numpy: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_python_py-numpy/py26-numpy/main.log for details.
Error: Problem while installing py26-numpy
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: It seems there are remnants from a previous attempt to build py26-numpy. Can you run `sudo port clean py26-numpy` and try again? Other than that, see the FAQ on failing ports: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#buildfails

Comment: clean didn't work. I submitted a ticket: #55987

Answer (score 0):

As the last line of the output says:

```
Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
```

When was numpy last working for you?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to be sure that this is a bug and not some mistake that I have made myself.

I don't use lumpy and have no idea what it is.

I.update MacPorts monthly. This is the first time I've ever seen this error. Some port that I use must depends on bumpy which is probably why it is installed.

Nothing I use fails to work. The only thing that failed was "port upgrade outdated'.